# Problem with Entity Framework entities relationship configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I want to create a relationship between the menu items and the restaurant - each menu item can have one restaurant and the restaurant can have multiple menu items, I would like to set this up in a one-to-many relationship, but after the 'update-database' command I get an error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_MenuItems_Restaurants_RestaurantId' on table 'MenuItems' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Any tips how to fix that?

```
public class Restaurant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Address { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public List<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; } = new List<MenuItem>();
}

public class MenuItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public Restaurant Restaurant { get; set; }
    public int RestaurantId { get; set; }
}
```

And I configure it like this in my `DbContext` class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Restaurant>()
            .HasOne(k => k.Owner)
            .WithMany(k => k.Restaurants)
            .HasForeignKey(k => k.OwnerId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    modelBuilder.Entity<MenuItem>()
            .HasOne(k => k.Restaurant)
            .WithMany(k => k.MenuItems)
            .HasForeignKey(k => k.RestaurantId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

    modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
}
```

Comment: Try keeping your cascading options similar for both tables. Either cascade or no action but not both.

Answer (score 1):

I would remove `HasOne` and replace it with `HasRequired` and map it's Id. Entity will make Foreign key on it's own.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Restaurant>()
            .HasRequired(k => k.Owner)
            .WithMany(k => k.Restaurants)
            .Map(k => k.MapKey("OwnerId"))
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<MenuItem>()
            .HasRequired(k => k.Restaurant)
            .WithMany(k => k.MenuItems)
            .Map(k => k.MapKey("RestaurantId"))
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);


        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue arises from the combination of cascade delete actions on the `Restaurant` entity and the `MenuItem` entity. To fix this issue, you should adjust the cascade delete behavior for one or both of your relationships.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Restaurant>()
        .HasOne(k => k.Owner)
        .WithMany(k => k.Restaurants)
        .HasForeignKey(k => k.OwnerId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    modelBuilder.Entity<MenuItem>()
        .HasOne(k => k.Restaurant)
        .WithMany(k => k.MenuItems)
        .HasForeignKey(k => k.RestaurantId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); // Change this to Restrict

    modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
}
```